# Python: averaging across repeat dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a numpy array with `datetime` stored in array `A` of size 100 as:

```
>>>A[0]
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

The other 99 elements are `datetime.datetime` objects also but few of them repeat e.g.

```
A[55] 
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 2, 0, 0)

A[56] 
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 2, 0, 0)
```

I have another array of `Temperature`s of same size as `A` with values corresponding to rows of `A` as:

```
Temperature[0] = 55
Temperature[55] = 40
Temperature[56] = 50
```

I am trying to obtain a new array from `A2` which only has unique datetime from `A` and takes average of corresponding temperature repeats.

So in this case I will have `A2` with only 1 `datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 2, 0, 0)` and temperature will be `0.5*(40+50) = 45`

I am trying to use pandas pivot table as:

```
DayLightSavCure = pd.pivot_table(pd.DataFrame({'DateByHour': A, 'Temp': Temperature}), index=['DateByHour'], values=['Temp'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
```

But the error is:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do actually concurr with @someone else, this could be achieved without digging into pandas. [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is really nice for this. Written for Python 3.5+(because of `statistics`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randint
import datetime
from statistics import mean

# Generate test data
dates = [datetime.datetime(2005, i % 12 + 1, 5, 5, 5, 5) for i in range(100)]
temperatures = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]

# Calculate averages

## Group data points by unique dates using `groupby`, `sorted` and `zip`
grouped = groupby(sorted(zip(dates, temperatures)), key=itemgetter(0))

##Calculate mean per unique date
averaged = [(key, mean(temperature[1] for temperature in values)) for key, values in grouped]

print(averaged)  # List of tuples
#[(datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5), 65.22222222222223), (datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5), 60.0),.......
print(dict(averaged))  # Nicer as a dict
{datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5): 48.111111111111114, datetime.datetime(2005, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5): 43.75, ..........
```

If you have to have two separate lists/iterators at the end of the calculation just apply `zip` to `averaged`.